# Show text and images in listview from server

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview, android-bitmap

I am trying to show images and text on listview , but it gives me error some Null Pointer Exception at **CustomList.java** i.e
`image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[position], 100, 50, false));`

**ImageListView.java**

```
public class ImageListView extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView listView;

    public static final String GET_IMAGE_URL="http://website.com/ImageUpload/getAllImages.php";

    public GetAlImages getAlImages;

    public static final String BITMAP_ID = "BITMAP_ID";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_list_view);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getURLs();
    }

    private void getImages(){
        class GetImages extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(ImageListView.this,"Downloading images...","Please wait...",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
                super.onPostExecute(v);
                loading.dismiss();
                System.out.println("Zinda 1");
                //Toast.makeText(ImageListView.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                CustomList customList = new CustomList(ImageListView.this,GetAlImages.imageURLs,GetAlImages.name,GetAlImages.bitmaps);
                System.out.println("Zinda 2");
                listView.setAdapter(customList);
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Zinda 3");
                    getAlImages.getAllImages();
                    System.out.println("Zinda 4");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
        GetImages getImages = new GetImages();
        getImages.execute();
    }

    private void getURLs() {
        class GetURLs extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(ImageListView.this,"Loading...","Please Wait...",true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                getAlImages = new GetAlImages(s);
                getImages();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String json;
                    while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        sb.append(json+"\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                }catch(Exception e){
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetURLs gu = new GetURLs();
        gu.execute(GET_IMAGE_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewFullImage.class);
        intent.putExtra(BITMAP_ID,i);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**//CustomList.java**

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private String[] urls;
    private String[] name;
    private Bitmap[] bitmaps;
    private Activity context;

    public CustomList(Activity context, String[] urls, String[] name,Bitmap[] bitmaps) {
        super(context, R.layout.image_list_view, urls);
        this.context = context;
        this.urls= urls;
        System.out.println("Singh 1");
        this.name= name;
        this.bitmaps= bitmaps;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_list_view, null, true);
        TextView textViewURL = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewURL);
        System.out.println("Singh 2");
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        System.out.println("Singh 3");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageDownloaded);

        textViewURL.setText(urls[position]);
        System.out.println("Singh 4");
        textViewName.setText(name[position]);
        System.out.println("Singh 5");
        image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[position], 100, 50, false));
        System.out.println("Singh 6");
        return  listViewItem;
    }
}
```

**//GetAlImages.java**

```
public class GetAlImages {

    public static String[] imageURLs;
    public static String[] name;
    public static Bitmap[] bitmaps;

    public static final String JSON_ARRAY="result";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String IMAGE_URL = "url";
    private String json;
    private JSONArray urls;


    public GetAlImages(String json){
        this.json = json;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            urls = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("Matru 1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getImage(JSONObject jo){
        URL url = null;
       // String name =null;
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(jo.getString(IMAGE_URL));
           // name = new String(jo.getString(NAME));
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("MAtru 2");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("MAtru 3");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("Matru 4");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }

    public void getAllImages() throws JSONException {
        bitmaps = new Bitmap[urls.length()];

        imageURLs = new String[urls.length()];
        name = new String[urls.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<urls.length();i++){

            name[i] = urls.getJSONObject(i).getString(NAME);
            System.out.println("MAtru 5");

            imageURLs[i] = urls.getJSONObject(i).getString(IMAGE_URL);

            JSONObject jsonObject = urls.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("MAtru 6");
            bitmaps[i]=getImage(jsonObject);
        }
    }
}
```

**//Logcat result**

```
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? I/System.out: Singh 2
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? I/System.out: Singh 3
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x5cceeb20)
01-01 10:35:43.882 1893-1990/? D/BstCommandProcessor-Application: Application crash has been observed. 
01-01 10:35:43.882 1893-1990/? W/BstCommandProcessor-Application: in sendHttpRequest, requestType is of CRASH_APP type but one of the requiredInfo is NULL, crashedApp = com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor.BstCrashedAppInfo@2e7ce858
01-01 10:35:43.882 1893-1990/? D/BstCommandProcessor-Application: in sendHttpRequest, request to send to (fqdn): http://10.0.2.2:2861/AppCrashedInfo
01-01 10:35:43.882 1893-1990/? D/BstCommandProcessor-Application: data: {"packageName":"com.package.name","shortPackageName":"com.package.name","versionCode":1,"versionName":"1.0"}
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5415 SIG: 9
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? D/AndroidRuntime: procName from cmdline: com.package.name
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.package.name
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? D/AndroidRuntime: file written successfully with content: com.package.name StringBuffer : ;com.package.name
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.package.name, PID: 5415
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:589)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.package.listview.CustomList.getView(CustomList.java:44)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16558)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16558)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16558)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16558)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16558)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16558)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16558)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1923)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1120)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1302)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1007)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5677)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
01-01 10:35:43.882 5415-5415/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 10:35:43.892 1708-1905/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.package.name (pid 5415) has died.
01-01 10:35:43.892 1708-1905/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{2e94b214 u0 com.package.name/com.package.listview.ImageListView t10}: app died, no saved state
01-01 10:35:43.892 1708-1719/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{2e9ee6cc u0 com.package.name/com.package.listview.ImageListView}
01-01 10:35:43.892 1708-1905/? D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: com.package.name activityName: com.package.name/.Login callingPackage:   bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
01-01 10:35:43.892 1708-1922/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{2e949cb4 u0 Loading... EXITING}
01-01 10:35:43.902 1708-1752/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '2e729764 com.package.name/com.package.name.Login (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
01-01 10:35:43.902 1708-1752/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '2e729764 com.package.name/com.package.name.Login (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-01 10:35:43.902 1908-1908/? D/GuidanceScreen: event === app_launch
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use convertView instead of listViewItem in adapter getView() method like this,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_list_view, null);
    TextView textViewURL = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewURL);
    System.out.println("Singh 2");
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    System.out.println("Singh 3");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageDownloaded);

    textViewURL.setText(urls[position]);
    System.out.println("Singh 4");
    textViewName.setText(name[position]);
    System.out.println("Singh 5");
    image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[position], 100, 50, false));
    System.out.println("Singh 6");
    return  convertView;
}
```

Comment: It's keep on Loading please wait... message and not showing any result ,
above code was ok . I added textview string name.
The reference is from 
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-using-php-mysql-android-studio/

Comment: It crashes the app , nothing else !